# Who owns a registered Microsoft Application Registration Portal app?

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

I logged into the Microsoft Application Registration Portal (https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/) and registered a new app. Then in a different browser, I logged in again but with a different account in the same Active Directory. The registered app was not visible.

Once an app is registered, who owns that app registration? How can other designated users in the same AD see an app registration to make changes? Should I use a service account when registering apps so the company always has access to app registrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, the App Registration Portal only shows you applications where you are explicitly marked as the owner of the application. Whenever you create a new application in the App Registration Portal, we explicitly mark the signed-in user as an owner. If you sign in with another user, you will not see the application show up on the list of apps because that user was not made an owner of the application. Yes, the app is registered in the same tenant as both of the users, but as mentioned, the owner link must explicitly be there.

There are two features coming down the pipeline in the near future which may solve issues you are facing related to owners and visibility of applications in App Reg Portal:

1. The ability to add owners to an application: We are working on a feature which would allow you to add other users as an explicit owner of an application. The initial app creator would be able to specify other users as explicit owners, and then those users would then be able to see the same app registration in the portal. This is currently available for AAD Users who sign into the portal.
2. The ability for administrators to see all applications in their tenant: We are working on a feature which would allow tenant administrators to be able to skip the "owner" check, and see all V2 applications registered in their tenant independent of being an explicit owner of an application. This is in hopes of allowing Company Administrators to manage all of the different V2 applications in their tenant.

We would love to hear more from you about the specific scenario you are trying to accomplish, and understand the feature set that would allow you to accomplish your goals. Please feel free post a comment explaining more about what you need, and whether you think one of the two features above will be sufficient for your scenario.

Comment: I'm currently building our first in-house AD integrated web app. Initially this is just the basic application infrastructure: AD integration, SQL connections, error handling, log files, etc. This is before the specific implementation bits are built. I'm building and testing this with my own developer Azure account before I migrate everything over to the corporate AD account. It's at that point our admins will want access to the app registration under the corporate AD account. Both of your proposed solutions sound like they may cover my scenario, depending upon when they will be rolled out.

Comment: For AAD users, the first feature is already available. If you go into the portal and simply add users as owners, you will see that they will gain access to the app registration in the portal.